# Receiving mouse EnterEvent and LeaveEvent on multiple popup widgets in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

After porting from Qt 4.8 to 5.4  I've got next problem...
When I'm showing multiple widgets with `Qt::Popup` flag set, only the first of them can receive mouse `enterEvent` or `leaveEvent`.
With 4.8.0 version all of popup widgets reacted on mouse entering or leaving.

Is this normal for Qt5 or some bug?

With code below only the first popup widget w1 reporting about `enterEvent` and `leaveEvent` on mouse moving. If `Qt::Popup` flag is not set all widgets report.

```
class PopupWidget : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PopupWidget( QWidget *parent = 0):QWidget(parent)
    {
    setWindowFlags( windowFlags() | Qt::Popup );
    setAutoFillBackground( true );
    setFixedSize( 100, 100 );
    }

protected:
    void    enterEvent(QEvent * event)
    { qDebug() << "enterEvent"; }

    void    leaveEvent(QEvent * event)
    { qDebug() << "leaveEvent"; }
};

void main()
{
    PopupWidget w1, w2, w3;

    w1.move( mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)) );
    w1.show();

    w2.move( mapToGlobal(QPoint(110,0)) );
    w2.show();

    w3.move( mapToGlobal(QPoint(220,0)) );
    w3.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. Seems, in Qt5 you can't use multiple popups at the same time. Even standard hover effects for buttons stop working if you open popup inside popup. I started to use `Qt::Tool` instead of `Qt::Popup` to avoid this problem.

In window constructor (I use `QFrame` as a base class):

```
setWindowFlags (Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

Opening window:

```
QFrame::show();
QApplication::setActiveWindow (this);
```

Handling focus out events:

```
bool event (QEvent * e)
{ if(e->type() == QEvent::WindowDeactivate) hide();
  return QFrame::event (e);
}
```

Global event filter to catch focus out events caused by wheel (install it on your main window):

```
bool eventFilter (QObject * obj, QEvent * e)
{ if(e->type() == QEvent::Wheel)
  { QWidget * w = qobject_cast <QWidget*> (obj);
    QWidget * aw = QApplication::activeWindow();
    if(w && !w->isActiveWindow() && aw != m_MainWindow) aw->hide();
  }
  return QObject::eventFilter (obj, e);
}
```

Comment: I used something like this, and it worked, but then I had this weird bug that on Windows 10, when you:
- show the widget
- hide it
- go to tablet mode
- go back to normal mode
- the widget gets shown again (but doesn't receive a showEvent() or anything).

I'm trying to figure out a way to still get the events on other widgets by using Qt::Popup, and it seems like I'll need to use my own mouse low level hook to know when the mouse is over the widget ... it seems a bit overkill though.